# Adding to mapped collection in NHibernate - transaction concern

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I use NHibernate with Fluent Configuration and I have simple Entity called `Administrator`:

```
public class Administrator : Entity
{
    public virtual ICollection<AdministratorClientAssociation> ClientsAssociation {get; protected set; }
    ...

    public virtual void AddClient(Client newClient)
    {
        var clientAssociation = new AdministratorClientAssociation()
        {
            AssociationDate = DateTime.Now,
            Client = newClient,
            ClientOwner = this
        };
        ClientsAssociation.Add(clientAssociation);
    }
}
```

Collection `ClientsAssociation` is `1:n` relation mapped by foreign key (`ClientOwner`) and it has set `Cascade.OnSaveUpdate`. The question is how does `NHibernate` deals with transactional concers in such situation? Normally I'd create transaction in which I'd add `Client`, and then `AdministratorClientAssociation`. Question is - should I wrap it to transaction everywhere I call `AddClient` (cause injecting session to entity looks horrible) or is it done automatically in case of mapped, cascaded collection?

Comment: What kind of application is this? In a web application it is common to wrap a request in a transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If NHibernate flushes the relations, it will be in the same transaction.

Eventhough a lot of people claim it is common to use a transaction around the entire request, it is also wrong.

All code between the start of a transaction and the end of it, should be considered an atomic operation. Either all of it succeeds or it fails.

If I try to add two clients, and the second one fails, should the first one be stored anyway? If that is the case, then adding a client is the atomic operation and the transaction should be around that piece of code.
If none of the clients should be stored when a single one fails, then the transaction should be around that batch.

The second question you should ask yourself is who will be responsible for managing transactions. There is no one answer to this question. It completely depends on how your application works. As an example, if you use CQRS, then the transaction should be managed by the component that is responsible for executing the commands.

Other architectures and requirements will demand other solutions.